# Given $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $2f(n)f(2n+1)=f(2n)(2f(n)+1)$ and $8f(n)>f(2n)>4(f(n)$. Find $f(12)$ in terms of $f(1)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Given $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$  such that $$2f(n)f(2n+1)=f(2n)(2f(n)+1)$$ and $$8f(n)>f(2n)>4(f(n)$$
> Find $f(12)$ in terms of $f(1)$
>
> Options:
>
> 1.$6^3 f(1) + 108$
>
> 2.$6f(1)+9$
>
> 3.$6^2f(1) +6$
>
> 4.$f(1) +108$

I tried putting in the values but couldn't figure out how to extract $f(12)$ out of it. Is there anyway to find any function $f(n)$ satisfying this? I also tried eliminating $f(2n+1)$ but couldn't. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you![image]

Comment: Are the values of $f$ natural?

Comment: Yes.  They must be natural...since the function if defined on natural numbers

Comment: Well, that does not follow. If you want to say the function is $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ you should say that explicitly.  And you should say whether you consider $0$ a natural number or not. Also, please edit to indicate your efforts, and to supply some context.  Where did you encounter this problem?  What makes it interesting?  Why should we imagine that it has a sensible answer?

Comment: @Ggsvdgdhddh $f(n) = \pi$ is a function defined on natural numbers whose values are not natural. So it remains open if $f$ can take non-natural values.

Comment: Wait, it **does not** simply follow the image of $f$ is ${\mathbb{N}}$? Does the question specify ${f : \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}}$ for you?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose, yes it does...but i don't know the tex commands for formatting that f:... Thing

Comment: @Ggsvdgdhddh ah it's all good, someone else edited that in for you just now

Comment: @lulu, I got this from a friend yesterday. Have been trying this since then...but could not make any progress. Can you help now? Please

Comment: I've edited for searchability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $n=1$ in the given equation. You get $$(*)\ 2f(1)f(3)=f(2)(2f(1)+1)$$ Hence $f(2)$ is even: $f(2)=2k$ for some natural $k$. We get $f(1)f(3)=k(2f(1)+1)$ and, since $x$ and $2x+1$ are relatively prime, $f(1)$ must divide $k$.

Let $k=lf(1)$, $l\in\mathbb{N}$. From $8f(1)>f(2)>4f(1)$ we have $8f(1)>2lf(1)>4f(1)$, that is $4>l>2$, hence $l=3$, so we proved that $f(2)=6f(1)$.

Now, from $(*)$ you get $f(3)=6f(1)+3$.

Can you make a next step yourself now?

Comment: One question: How do you prove that $x$ and $2x+1$ are relatively prime?

Comment: Indeed, from $2\nmid 2f(n)+1$ and $\gcd(f(n),2f(n)+1)$, we find $2f(n)\mid f(2n)$. Being squeezed between $4f(n)$ and $8f(n)$, we conclude that $f(2n)=6f(n)$ and $f(2n+1)=6f(n)+3$

Comment: if $d$ divides both of them, then $d$ divides their difference: $(2x+1)-x=x+1$, and next $d$ divides $(x+1)-x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an explicit description of **all** values $f(n)$ in terms of $f(1)$:

**Claim:** If $n=\sum_{i=0}^ma_i2^i$ with $a_i\in\{0,1\}$ and $a_m=1$, then
$$\tag1 f(n)=6^mf(1)+3\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}a_i6^i$$
*Proof:*
From the functional equation, we find that using $\gcd(2f(n),2f(n)+1)=1$ that $2f(n)\mid f(2n)$. Then with $4f(n)<f(2n)<8f(n)$, we conclude
$$\tag2 f(2n)=6f(n).$$
Moreover,
$$\tag3f(2n+1)=\frac{f(2n)(2f(n)+1)}{2f(n)}=3(2f(n)+1)=f(2n)+3.$$
Note that $(2)$ and $(3)$ uniquely determine all $f(n)$ in terms of $f(1)$. Hence for a proof of the claim by induction, it suffices to show that the right hand side of $(1)$

- equals $f(1)$ for $n=1$,
- grows by a factor of $6$ when $n$ is doubled,
- and grows by $3$ when even $n$ gets increased by $1$.

The first is trivial. The second follows because doubling increases $m$ by $1$ and pushes all $a_i$ one up. The third follows because the only change is that $a-0$ switches from $0$ to $1$. $\square$

In particular,
$$f(12)=f(1100_2)=6^3f(1)+3\cdot 6^2.$$